# Android - How to make an progressBar touching a bottom screen border

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I want a ProgressBar that is touching a bottom border of screen but with this piece of code, I am getting an little space between bar and screen border:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".Whatever" >

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is what I am getting:

[image: this space i am still getting]

is there any way to remove that space?

Comment: Have you tried setting margin bottom to zero?

Comment: I have, it doesent help.

Comment: Hi David, did you get this solved?

Comment: Hi, i didn't because i moved from that project.

Comment: "Thanks for anwsers." is in appropriate (read help->tour) as well as incorrect English, so just leave out the chit-chat next time.

Answer (score 1):

Make your parent layout height as fill_parent and set progressbar height as match_parent.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the solution to use a custom `progressDrawable` without any paddings like this:

progress_bar_progress.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/accent"/>
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

And then reference it in your `ProgressBar`:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#1A000000"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:indeterminateOnly="false"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar_progress" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hack that could work:

- Create a LinearLayout for your whole view; set the width and height to fill_parent for it and orientation to vertical
- Now, since you know how many components will be in your view, just give them the right amounts of weights; except the last progressbar
- For the progressbar, give it the smallest of all; that way, it will be pushed all the way to the bottom;
- Finally, using padding to reduce the space between it and the window (bottom)

That is what I can think of unless you want to create a custom style for the progressbar as mentioned in a comment above

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around.I am basically adding a layout_marginBottom="-4dp" to my ProgressBar and wrapped it inside a RelativeLayout and aligned it to the bottom of the parent view.This changes may break your app in the future.For a better solution design a custom progress bar with your own custom drawable which you can align correctly and occupies less canvas space compared to the progressBarStyleHorizontal.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/imageButton”
android:layout_width="40dip"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:contentDescription="@string/descrp"
android:scaleType="center"
android:src="@drawable/some_drawable”
android:visibility="visible" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textview”
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textStyle="bold" />
//changes
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/some_other_id"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp" />
</RelativeLayout></RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30009811/how-to-make-an-progressbar-touch-bottom-screen-border-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this for a while now. My conclusion:
There is no way to archieve this behaviour **with XML** for arbitrary screen sizes.
On some screen sesolutions the progress bar will always be misplaced a little.

My simple solution: Set the Y of the progressbar **programmatically** to the Y of the super view/layout

```
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

    progressBar.setY(layout.getY() - progressBar.getHeight() / 2);
}
```

Works like a charm and for all screen sizes.