# ProgressBar Align Bottom Edge of Listitem

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-progressbar, listitem

How to make `progressBar` align bottom edge of listitem without any margin. 
I dont know how to place it to become bottom edge of ListItem. `android:layout_alignParentBottom` is not working how it should, still have ~4dp bottom margin.

Below XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/zam_ll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/listview_selector"
    android:longClickable="true" >

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/zam_status"
         android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
         android:src="@drawable/status_zrealizowane"
         android:visibility="visible" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mz_kod"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mz_numer"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linright"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:lines="1"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@string/title_kontrahent_detail"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mz_numer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linright"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/roz_photo"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:lines="1"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:text="@string/kontrahenci_kod"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/roz_photo"
            android:layout_width="22dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/lista_zam" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linright"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mz_wartosc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Wartość"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mz_ilosc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ilość"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>



    </RelativeLayout>
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/mz_progress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks a lot!

P.S. i know that "-5dp" margin wont work :)

Comment: add `ProgressBar` as footer of `ListView`

Comment: i want `progressBar` for each, LIST ITEM

Comment: why `android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"`

Comment: to move it below margin.. but as i said it is not working :)

Comment: better add a screen shots of what you want.

Comment: Specify width as `wrap_content`.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dqRHG.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you `ProgressBar` is suffering from one its ancestors' paddings. Make your all its parents have `padding_bottom` set to `0`.

Also add zero padding to that `ProgressBar` and see whether it sticks to the bottom or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can create  `RelativeLayout`  and remove `android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"`

```
<RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/mz_progress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: still there is margin below progress bar

Comment: @Filip Okay .Use RelativeLayout instead of all LinearLayout

Comment: btw. i am using `RelativeLayout` not `LinearLayout`

Comment: @Filip http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22414758/android-how-to-make-an-progressbar-touching-a-bottom-screen-border